Rule for if cell has data manually added it changes text colour
Hi i have a sheet with months and years horizontally and a location vertically per cell.
I will ad a score in each cell for the different locations, but not add scores in all cells each month as we will not review all locations each month.
The score last added will be carried through untill a new score is added manually, the rule for the calculation, i have configured.
But I will need help with a rule for a different colour text if value is added manually and not a formula is it possible??
alternatively another solution ie. highlighting etc. so i an get an overview over what cells are manually added.
hope to get help from the community, cheers
L

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Conditional formatting using =ISFORMULA() seems like what you need.
